# Question on a step of the proof of Theorem 1.25 of Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

> Theorem 1.25: Suppose $ \phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n}) $ and $ \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} \phi =1 $ .
>   Also, let $\phi_{\epsilon}(x)=\frac{\phi\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)}{\epsilon^n}$.Moreover , suppose that : $ \psi(x)= \operatorname{esssup}_{|y|\geq |x|} |\phi(y)|$ is in $ L^1(\mathbb{R^n}) $ and $ f \in L^p(\mathbb{R^n}) $ for some $ p \in [1,\infty] $ Then $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (f \ast \phi_{\epsilon})(x)=f(x)$ for every $ x \in L_f $ where $L_f$ is the Lebesgue set of $ f $ .

In the course of the proof the author obtains for $ x \in L_f$ and for an arbitrary $\delta > 0 $ an $h>0 $ such that : 
$$
\frac{1}{r^n} \int_{|t|<r} |f(x-t)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}t < \delta , \quad \forall 0<r \leq h
$$

Then the author considers the function 
$$
g(r)= \int_{S^{n-1}} |f(x-ry)-f(x)| \mathrm{d} \sigma_y
$$ where $ \sigma $ is the surface measure on $ S^{n-1} $. Then he considers the function 
$$G(r)=\int_{0}^{r} g(s)s^{n-1} \mathrm{d}s 
$$

Now the step that I do not quite get is why the following calculation is fully justified :
$$
\begin{split}
 \int_{ |t|<h} |f(x-t)-f(x)| &\frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \psi\left(\frac{t}{ \epsilon}\right) \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{h} r^{n-1}g(r) \epsilon^{-n} \psi\left(\frac{r}{\epsilon}\right) \mathrm{d}r \\
&= \left. G(r) \epsilon^{-n} \psi\left(\frac{r}{\epsilon}\right) \right|_0^h-\int_0^h G(r)\,\mathrm{d}\left( \epsilon^{-n} \psi\left(\frac{r}{\epsilon}\right)\right)
\end{split}$$

While it clear for me why $ G $ and $ \psi $ is differentiable ( $ G $ because of the Lebesgue's differentiation theorem and $ \psi $ because it is decreasing [ in $ r $ ] ) I am not sure why the  integration by parts formula here is valid. For example I know that if R and Q are both absolutely continuous then we do have that $ \int_{a}^{b} RQ^{\prime}+QR^{\prime}=R(b)Q(b)-R(a)Q(a) $ but I am not sure that  this applies here.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: A function $ f \; : \; [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ is absolutely continuous if for each $ \epsilon >0 $ $ \exists \delta > 0 $ such that if  $ {(a_i,b_i)}_{i=1}^{N} $ are disjoint intervals with $ \sum_{i=1}^{N} (b_i-a_i) < \delta \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{N} (F(b_i)-F(a_i)) < \epsilon $

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was nonsense. Anyway, the function $\psi$ is at least of bounded variation and we have the integration-by-parts rule for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals. But I really think the last summand has to be interpreted as Riemann-Stieltjes integral and not as $\int_0^h G(r)\frac{d}{dr}(\epsilon^{-n}\psi(\epsilon^{-1}r))\,dr$.

Comment: I changed the last integral to match the notation in Stein's book. I'm pretty sure that this is to be understood as Stieltjes integral and you can use the integration by parts formula for these. The boundary terms might still not be quite correct (should be replaced by one-sided limits), but this does not matter in this context of the proof.

Comment: @ImpendingUncertainty: There is another small problem here: $\psi$ is a function on $\mathbb R^n$, therefore it cannot be applied to $\frac r \varepsilon$. To be rigorous, after the change of variable you should write $\psi (\frac {r u} \varepsilon)$, where $u$ is some unit vector (it doesn't matter which one, since $\psi$ has spherical symmetry).